# Is there a word for one side in a pair?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for one side in a pair? In a conversation it would the the interlocutor, but I'm looking for a generic term.

Comment: Example sentence needed in single-word requests. After six years it’s unlikely to be forthcoming, so let’s kill it.

Comment: Moiety is that word

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The English word for "one of a pair" is in fact "pair". You can ask: "Where is the pair to this shoe?" "Pair" has two meanings.

Comment: But it is not used in isolation for a single member of the set.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Every member of parliament has a "pair" in the opposite party.

Comment: Yes, every MP has a pair. This is not 'in isolation'. I can't pick a random element in a set with two members, take it to show it to a friend, and call it a 'pair'. 'One of a pair', yes.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going with "counterpart", as suggested to me off-site. Thanks for the feedback though!

Comment: That's great. You should still provide a definition and explain why this word particularly met your need.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of those occasions when one realizes the unique abilities of each language. English with most number of words among the world languages, does not have a word for each member of a pair. We, hence, use the word "pair" (as in "where is the other pair?") when we mean a member of the pair. In Persian we do not have this problem as there is a word for members of the dyad. The pair or couple is "Joft" (جفت) and each member of that pair is a "lengeh" (لنگه.) Persian also have a word for a mismatched pair: "lengeh be lengeh!"

when

Comment: Good news and bad news. First the good news. I have found an English term for "one side of a pair." That word is "leg" and it is used in the same sense as the Persian "lengeh" (لنگه) In capital markets usually each trade is logged in a pair, one from the buy and the other from the sell side. You would hear a trader in Wall Street saying "yours didn't match my leg" or "where is the other leg of trade?"

Comment: The bad news is that this is part of a specialized lingo. But the word is also used in common parlance to refer to the two parts of the itinerary of a trip. What makes this truly exciting is that the words "leg" and "leng" are from the same Indo-European root and they mean exactly the same thing: leng means leg.

Comment: It is not correct to say that *leg* refers to one of **two** parts of a trip. It refers to any one part of a multi-part trip. So your trip could have any number of legs, not just two; to find examples, just search for "this trip has three legs" on google books. As far as the use of *leg* in capital markets, can you provide some sort of a source? All I found is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_trade) and [this](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/leg.asp), both of which sound a bit different from what you are saying.

Answer (score 4):

Until we find a more complicated esoteric word that matches your requirements, try "complement" for a while.

Comment: Of course something can only be a complement to an aforementioned something else. A boot is not a complement. It's only a complement if you already have the other boot. And then you're still missing a name for that original boot you already have.

Comment: Are you saying if I order a double vodka then one vodka must be complementary, sounds like a good idea as long as the barmaid doesn't have an account here. :)

Comment: Now I've made a pointless quip I've had a thought. If we agree that one of the pair is the other ones complement then surely the 'aforementioned something else' is also the complement of the other one (the original complement). So in fact any pair is made up of two complements, one half of a pair is a complement, the other half is the other complement.

Answer (score 2):

Given that a pair is often referred to by the use of the Greek derived "dyad" you could use "monad" (also derived from the Greek) for a single part of the pair (although monad doesn't specifically describe part of a pair as much as it does a single unit of any kind).

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dyad

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monad

Answer (score 2):

Cugel uses "part" to describe their response, https://english.stackexchange.com/a/164938/227352, so why not just use "part" to describe part of a pair?  Everyone knows a pair is only comprised of two objects, so it should be obvious that there could be only two parts.

Answer (score 1):

[Odd](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd) (Oxford Online Dictionary, def 3): As in the odd glove. Half of a pair.

Comment: I believe this is the same sense as "odd-man out". This choice is good for many contexts.

Answer (score 1):

**Partner**, as in "howdy partner," based on the latin partitio, "partition"

Comment: This is wrong. OED: **Partner** Etymology: Probably an alteration of *parcener* n. ***parcener* 1. A person who shares, or has a part in, something with another or others; a partner; a sharer, a partaker.)**

Comment: @Greybeard the Anglo-Norman French parcener, is based on the Latin partitio.

Comment: I see what you mean but, *partitio* tends to division, whereas *parcener* goes to mutual interest.

Comment: @Greybeard quibbling over the latin's "tendency" to division opposed to its sense of relatedness, I'll refrain from, but wrong I'm not.  Besides, the point is that "partner" in English suggests some-one/thing belonging to (or formerly belonging to) a whole: "my partner in life", a "partner in crime", "she's my business partner".  As such, it gets pretty close to a word in English "for one side in a pair" which can be used in isolation (see Edwin Ashworth's complaint on the accepted answer).  Moreover, "partner" is far more natural than "part" for a pairing, which another answer provided.

Comment: The matter is complicated, though, by the fact that a partnership can have more than two partners.

Answer (score 1):

How about mate, which implies pairing to one other thing, etc, or to a group?

> 3 : one of a pair: such as
>
> a : either member of a couple and especially a married couple
>
> b : either member of a breeding pair of animals
>
> c : either of two matched objects

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mate

Answer (score -2):

**Bifurcate**:

[— vb
1.  to fork or divide into two parts or branches](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bifurcate)

**Branch**:

[12.
to divide into separate parts or subdivisions; diverge: The main road branches off to the left.
13.
to expand or extend, as business activities: The bank has plans to branch throughout the state.
verb (used with object)
14.
to divide into branches or sections.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/branch)

**Moiety**:

[Moiety Moi"e*ty (moi"[-e]*t[y^]), n.; pl. {Moieties} (moi"[-e]*t[i^]z). [F. moiti['e], L. medietas, fr. medius middle, half. See {Mid}, a., and cf. {Mediate}, {Mediety}.] 1. **One of two equal parts**; a half; as, a moiety of an estate, of goods, or of profits; the moiety of a jury, or of a nation. --Shak. [1913 Webster]](http://en.academic.ru/dic.nsf/cide/112980/Moiety)

Comment: I love the latter :)